# Получение размеров окна. (Java)

Tags: java

Буду краток. Как получить размеры экрана (На Windows) юзера (Если это вообще возможно). Можно объект, так даже лучше. Или надо делать какие - то ассемблерные вставки?
Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предполагаю, что под размерами вы имеете в виду разрешение экрана.

Самый простой способ - воспользоваться классом `java.awt.Toolkit`:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
int width = screenSize.width;
int height = screenSize.height;
```

Если вам нужно больше информации о графических устройствах, или речь идет о системе с несколькими дисплеями, вам нужны `GraphicsEnvironment` и `GraphicsDevice` из того же пакета. Для основного устройства:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = device.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = device.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Для выбора конкретного устройства из числа доступных вызовите `getScreenDevices()`:

```
GraphicsDevice[] devices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
```

и обращайтесь по индексу:

```
devices[0].getDisplayMode()
devices[1].getDisplayMode()
...
```